# JMeter gradle plugin causes build to fail with exception

Tags: gradle, jmeter, gradle-plugin

I am trying to use the JMeter gradle plugin to run jmeter tests and produce a log on build.

Currently, I have added this to my build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'jmeter'

buildscript{
    repositories{
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies{
        classpath "com.github.kulya:jmeter-gradle-plugin:1.3.4-2.13"
    }
}

jmeterRun.configure{
    jmeterTestFiles = [file("src/test/jmeter/gradleTest.jmx")]
    enableReports = true
}
```

However when I run the build.gradle file using 'jmeterRun' I get the following error:

```
org.gradle.tooling.BuildException: Could not execute build using Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.2.1-bin.zip'.
```

[Here is the full error message](http://pastebin.com/zYDJsWGu)

and it suggests I check the jmeter logs for more information, though no new logs are created and there is no entry in the existing log related to this error.

I had previously tried to use the plugin as suggested [here](https://github.com/jmeter-gradle-plugin/jmeter-gradle-plugin/wiki/Getting-Started), however I was getting an error saying the plugins block was not correct (despite being copy-pasted).

How do I get the JMeter plugin working properly?

Comment: The exception states that you should look at JMeter logs: `Something went wrong during jmeter test execution, Please see jmeter logs for more information`. SO what does JMeter log say?

Comment: I cant find the JMeter log. Its not created in the directory that it says it should be created in: src/test/jmeter (Which does already exist in my project, with the .jmx file). The only other jmeter.log file I have is from running JMeter as an application, and it has no logs related to this.

Comment: I have also looked under /build/jmeter/ but could not find a log...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regardless of whether or not your test uses one one, a jmeter.properties file is required, otherwise an error will occur. Normally this error should say that
`Could not read JMeter properties file`
according to [here](https://github.com/kulya/jmeter-gradle-plugin/wiki#advanced-configuration).

I am still unsure why a jmeter.log file was created.